# Finding an accurate mathmatical function from a plot/ 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, function, plot

How would i go about finding the mathmatical function from a graphical plot/ 2d array? e.g.

```
line = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
print(findfunction(line))
>y=x

line2 =[5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19] 
print(findfunction(line2))
>y=2x+5
```

And so on for ploynomials, exponentials and everything in between.

I understand for some lines there either may be no function**, or i may have to break it down into ranges to get anything that closely resembals a function but i can't think of how to do this, aside brute force but that dosen't seem reliable.

**no function?  kinda makes sense that there is a function to describe every possible line/ curve, right?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html

Comment: is this assuming the index of the "line array" is x = 1,2,3,4 etc.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/basic-curve-fitting-of-scientific-data-with-python-9592244a2509

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Answer (score 0):

For linear equations, you could simply use NumPy's polyfit. Assuming the line arrays you mentioned have values x = 1,2,3,4... we could do the following

```py
def fit_to_function(x, y):
    """
    fit_to_function(x, y)
    x: list of x values
    y: list of y values
    returns: list of y values that fit the function
    """
    x, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    return f"y = {x}x + {b}"
```

Testing:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]

print(fit_to_function(x, y))
```

Output:

```
y = 1.9999999999999998x + 5.000000000000003
```

Optional: if you want to round it like in your original question

```
import numpy as np

def fit_to_function(x, y):
    """
    fit_to_function(x, y)
    x: list of x values
    y: list of y values
    returns: list of y values that fit the function
    """
    x, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    x, b = round(x, 2), round(b, 2)
    return f"y = {x}x + {b}"
```

Output:

```
y = 2.0x + 5.0
```